# PHP Error - False Positive Using IF Statement

Tags: php

I have been looking at this for hours and can't seem to find the error that is giving me false positives on passed and fails, If anyone could help please help.

It is basically to show an array then creating a large amount of information and placing it into a table,

Any help would be great

the problem is that when they are under 40 they fail, it will then add to a variable and say they have failed but its giving false positives and even saying people are failing when they are not below 40 you may need to refresh a few times.

Thanks

```
        //Checks to see if they have passed
        if($examark > $examPassmark AND $courseworkmark > $courseworkPassmark)
        {
            $mark = 'Pass';
            $passed = $passed + 1;
        }else{
            $mark = 'Fail';
            $failed = $failed + 1;
        }
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve that if a student is less than 40 in any then he should be declared fail?

Comment: This question is full of code; it's not clear **what exactly** doesn't work nor **where** that particular piece of code is. Please keep your code relevant and only post the problematic snippet and state your problem clearly.

Comment: yeah basically if its under 40 they have failed

Comment: well! then good news is that it's working exactly you are saying on my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//For loop to loop a total of 18 times
for($i = 0; $i <= 18; $i++)
```

You loop 19 times. Change to $i < 18.

All your statistics will be wrong, since you have a hidden random row.

Comment: You are Right I thank you so much, cant believe i missed that thanks a lot friend.

Answer (score 0):

This would also be better

```
//Checks to see if they have passed
if($examark >= $examPassmark AND $courseworkmark >= $courseworkPassmark)
{
    $mark = 'Pass';
    $passed = $passed + 1;
    $com = '';
}else{
    $mark = 'Fail';
    $failed = $failed + 1;
    if($examark >= $examPassmark)
    {
       $com = 'Resit CourseWork';
    }
    else if($courseworkmark >= $courseworkPassmark)
    {
      $com = 'Resit Exam';
    }
    else
    {
       $com = 'Resit Both';
    }
}
```

Your current script doesn't detect the == case so you are going to have random false negative.